# Reload iframe onclick button instead reloading page Angular2

Tags: html, iframe, angular2-routing

I want to reload search data again when popup is closed, I mean my app will go as an iframe in the main web app, so On button click, I don't want to reload my whole page as **window.location.reload()**  , I want only my data should be reloaded,

Example- When I click yes in popup to remove something and when I close popup, It should reload the search data,

Suggest me for routing/any other method instead of window reload

Comment: If you want only your data to be reloaded, you'll have to, er, write code to do that.  Do you have a question about the code you're writing?

Comment: If  you really want to reload the data means why don't you call the function for loading the data again in the popup close event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reload the function instead of reloading the window.
Seems like if u have function for loading the data like

```
foo(data:any){
     --your code for loading data and binding
}

//popup close event

close(){ 

   this.foo();

}
```

this will help u to reassign the data without reloading the window